# Is there a limit on instagram's api for oauth tokens

Tags: api, instagram

Sorry this question might seem a little dumb, but does instagram limit access to the access tokens they give you. I know on twitter you're limited to 100,000 access tokens, so does instagram do the same on their api? Lets say I have 150,000 users, will instagram's api allow those users to be authorized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official [documentation](http://instagram.com/developer/limits/) does not say about any limits about access tokens. However they have limits per hour.

> Global rate limits are applied inclusive of all API calls made by an app over the 1-hour sliding window, regardless of the particular endpoint. The limits are applied independently from each other; authenticated calls are not counted against the rate limit for unauthenticated calls and vice-versa.

So the answer is No, as of now.